# Graphing a Riemann Sum

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm supposed to use the Riemann sum to approximate the area under the graph of $f(x)= 2e^{-x}$ on the interval $1$ to $2$ using $n=5$ sub-intervals with the selected points as the right end points

Is there a graphing generator I can use on a website I can use to graph this? I have done others but that $e$ is not making it work.

I just need the graph. I know the answer it is .420129

Comment: Just sketch out the graph by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's possible using wolframalpha.com, and you could try:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=riemann+sum+for+2e%5Ex+using+5+intervals+in+the+interval+%5B1%2C2%5D